# Android: Inflate listview using its android:id

Tags: android, android-layout

I don't know if this is possible, is it possible for me to inflate a listview using only its id? Thanks.

Comment: I think you should only inflate _layouts_ i.e. `ViewGroup`s. Maybe what you want is to set the visibility of a View from GONE to VISIBLE?

Comment: thanks laurent. yeah i tried inflating an xml file. that works. however, when i try expanding using the id of the root layout in this file, everything fails.

Comment: Judging from the doc, it seems that the id has to be a xml file. Not a View. Could you please tell us why you need this to help find another solution?

Comment: i want to only inflate a specific portion of an xml file, and not the whole file.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be confused about the difference between a component ID and a layout ID.

A layout ID refers to the name of a layout XML file. For example, if you have a layout named `res/layout/home_activity.xml`, its ID would be stored as `R.layout.home_activity`.

A component ID refers to the identity of a UI component inside an existing layout.  So, inside your `home_activity.xml` layout you might have `<TextView android:id="@+id/my_textview" />`. The ID of that View is `R.id.my_textview`.

You can only inflate layouts using a layout ID. 'Inflating' a component ID doesn't make any sense, unless you inflate a layout as a child of a View with a specific ID.

Comment: thanks dave. that really helped clear my confusion. but do you know how i can "inflate a layout as a child of a View with a specific ID"? an example would really help.

Comment: Well, say you already have a reference to a (e.g.) `LinearLayout`, let's call it `root`. And say you've just inflated a layout, so you now have a `View` called `myInflatedLayout`. You could do `root.addView(myInflatedLayout)`.

Answer (score 1):

Now that things are more clear, I suggest that you set your 'Inflatable ListView' as [`gone`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android%3avisibility) in your Layout file using:

```
<ListView android:visibility="gone" ... />
```

Then just set it to visible using [`View.setVisibility()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) whenever you want it to 'inflate'

```
mHiddenListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the layout inflater [inflates](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/LayoutInflater.html#inflate%28int,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) any View from the Resource id.

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService
      (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
listView = inflater.inflate(R.id.your_listview, parentView );
```

Edit: Well, it has to be a layout ID referring to some xml layout, not a component of it. Why don't you create a new xml containing that view component that you want to extract?

Comment: thanks reno. however, it says that the resource type is not valid.

Comment: Sure? Quoting the doc: `resource: ID for an XML layout resource to load (e.g., R.layout.main_page)`

Comment: the resource id has to be a layout xml file. i however, want to expand only a specific layout within a larger xml file.