# Android: Xml file, inflate

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Andriod: Inflate listview using its android:id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673911/andriod-inflate-listview-using-its-androidid)

With regard to the following qn : [Android Custom Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7038986/android-custom-listview)
I would like to know how the following statement:

```
convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, null);
```

can be implemented if the contents of listitem_row.xml are part of a larger xml file. i.e., i only want to inflate this specific part of the larger xml file. Thanks.

Comment: ... Reminds me of [something](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673911/andriod-inflate-listview-using-its-androidid). Please avoid duplicate by modifying your original question ;)

Comment: You have posted this question 3 times in the last hour !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just create another XML contain those specific parts you need, and inflate it. Please learn the basic first.

You can refer to one of my tutorials on ListView: http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/06/12/create-application-launcher-as-a-list/

Comment: thanks xjaphx, you helped me solve my problem! really appreciate your help.